# Laravel deferred service dependency

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to retrieve a deferred service from the IoC in an other service provider fails.

```
class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

    // ...

    public function register() {
        $router = \App::make('router'); // gets resolved
        $hash = \App::make('hash'); // throws an error (Class hash does not exists)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Changing `$deffered = false` to `true` in the `HashingServiceProvider` resolves this problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Using a static factory to try to do dependency injection.

Comment: It is not static - are you familiar with laravel's IoC?

Comment: `Yes::it_is($static)`

Comment: Only because you retrieve it that way, doesn't mean that it is static behind the scenes. All it does is grabbing the shared instance from the IoC that gets provided by the responsible service provider.

Comment: Shared **globally scoped** instance. It is static. Globall application state is still global application stat, even if you call it by different name. Stop drinking the damned coolaid.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question. Why does everything else gets resolved, but a deferred service doesn't? Instead of poking around on design principles it would be nice to hear an answer to the **actual** question. Deferred or not - behind the scenes it works all the same (should).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on the *"What am I doing wrong?"* part of your question? Which error message exactly do you get? Which part of the error message is not clear to you? What have you expected to happen instead? And as your question already contains the answer (setting `$deffered` to `true` causes the error, you name the error as doing wrong, following common logic then, setting `$deffered` to `true` is what you do wrong) it's perhaps necessary you elaborate as well what you're trying to do and why certain details are of uttermost importance to you.

Comment: I gave exactly 2 tags - php AND laravel. None of you seem to have ever worked with this framework. Because $deffered = true was on the Laravel its own Service. That wasn't my code and I am not willing to go and poke around in core Classes. All I said is that you could eliminate that error by changing a line in the framewroks's code. Honestly guys, my question was very laravel specific and some aspects were self explaining (if you know laravel, as did the Joseph Silber).

Comment: @MK: With all due respect, you wrote in your question that you changed that core code value. So it was you - and only you - whoke poked around in core Classes. To which other assumption have I come  to than assuming doing that is okay to you? Additionally, you didn't share the error message. Which I highlighted and which is apart being Laravel or anything else is just good practice with a question on SO as well as explaining the detail of your problem. This is important in rating a question for keeping the content on this website.

Comment: @hakre I see your point!

Comment: Well then now review at least your questions title: "Laravel deferred service dependency" - don't you think this is - at least - a little misleading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're relying on another service provider, do it in the `boot` method:

```
class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

    public function boot ()
    {
        $hash = $this->app['hash'];
    }

}
```

Here's a quote from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#service-providers):

> The `register` method is called immediately when the service provider is registered, while the `boot` command is only called right before a request is routed. So, if actions in your service provider rely on another service provider already being registered, or you are overriding services bound by another provider, you should use the `boot` method.

Comment: Thank you sir! I've must have missed that.